# cakephp model relationship

Tags: cakephp, model

Below is a Users table and a Friendships table.
When a given User logs in, I retrieve all Friendships where $id == user_a_id OR $id == user_b_id.

```
| Friendships |
| id | user_a_id | user_b_id | created | modified |
|  1 |     1     |     2     | created | modified |
|  2 |     1     |     5     | created | modified |
|  3 |     3     |     1     | created | modified |
|  4 |     2     |     4     | created | modified |
|  5 |     3     |     2     | created | modified |

| Users |
| id | first_name | last_name | created | modified |
|  1 | Barrack    | Obama  | -- | -- |
|  2 | John       | McCain | -- | -- |
```

When Obama logs in, I want to display a list of his friends names, so the query result needs to also contain 2 rows from the Users table.

How do you set this relationship up with Cake??

Is it Friendship hasMany Users? and is there any tutorials regarding this anywhere?

Thanks

EDIT:

I just want to be able to specify the following:

```
$this->set('friendships', $this->Friendship->find('all' , IncludeBothUsersInfoInQuery ));
```

So that each friendship in the view looks like the following, and I can have access to both users data in the view:

```
[Friendship]
    [id]
    [user_a_id]
    [user_b_id]
    [created]
    [modified]
        [User_A_Info]
            [id]
            [first_name]
            [last_name]
            [created]
            [modified]
        [User_B_Info]
            [id]
            [first_name]
            [last_name]
            [created]
            [modified]
```

Answer (score 1):

Friendship belongsTo User_A and User_B (you need 2 belongsTo relationships), remember to set the foreign key. You're familiar with containable, right? If not, look it up, you'll see how to query the data you need. You might also want to set User hasMany Friendship.